# Visual Studio adds caret to command line when run without debugging

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, console-application, caret

In a Visual Studio *Console Application* project, going to the project's properties' *Debug* tab and setting the *Command line arguments* to "<>" (including double-quotes), and using, *Start without debugging*, to run the following C# code:

```cs
class Program
{  static void Main(string[] args)
   {  Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
   }
}
```

..then the output will be:

```
^<^>
```

That is, it will insert a caret before each bracket. Running the code by using *Start debugging* or removing the double-quotes from the *Command line arguments* box will output <> (i.e., no added carets).

I have recreated this in VS2010 and VS2013 using C# and Visual Basic.

Why does this happen and is there a way to stop it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Console commands interpret `>` and `<` as redirectors. Prefixing them with a caret "escapes" that special meaning so they are interpreted as regular characters.

Comment: So, why doesn't it also do that when using *Start Debugging*, or when run from the command line. It only does that when using *Start Without Debugging* and the <> is in quotes. It seems more like a bug in VS to me.

Comment: I just found this by searching after realizing that VS is doing the same thing with '&' when using Start Without Debugging. It's very annoying. No matter what is special on the command line, the program should not be receiving the escape characters!